# Rails LoadError: cannot load rack/handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error when starting my rails application in developemnt

```
bundle exec rails s -e development 3010
```

error:

```
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/3010 (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:76:in `try_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:63:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

`rails s -p 3010`

By default, it works in development environment.

And if you still want to run with this statement, then try:

`bundle exec rails s -e development -p 3010`

You are missing -p here.

Answer (score 0):

You can be using the below comment,

```
rails s -p whatever_you_want
```

Here -p indigates the port number of the app

```
Example:  rails s -p 8030     // Here 8030 is the port number
```

If you want to run the rails app means, execute the below URL,

```
bundle exec rails s -e development -p 8030
```

Here -e refers the environment you are going run the rails app.